# My excel file is in Germany(German) format and would like to change to English(UK) format

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried multiple codes such as this

[image]

```
Sub DateFixer()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In Selection
            v = r.Text
            r.Clear
            r.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
            r.Value = DateSerial(Mid(v, 7, 4), Mid(v, 4, 2), Left(v, 2)) + TimeSerial(Mid(v, 12, 2), Mid(v, 15, 2), Right(v, 2))
        Next r
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

and this

```
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Range("A1:A3").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss am/pm
"
```

and this

```
Sub changeformat()

    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'MsgBox lastrow
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat = ("dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss am/pm")
    Next i

End Sub
```

But it still did not change my DateTime to 9/12/20 09:28:00 am. May i know what did i do wrongly?

[image]

Comment: Is your data a real *Date* or a String that just looks like a date?

Comment: String that contains both date and time

Comment: Applying a NumberFormat to a String does exactly nothing (why should it?)

Comment: Insufficient information.  Can you change the date format manually by selecting the cell and changing the format?  eg to `General` (should => a number like `44228.32205`)?

Comment: its shows a general format with no specific number format

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/299437/52365?

Comment: I tried it, it still didnt work. The following below also didnt work. Sub changeformat()
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells
    .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, xlDMYFormat)
    .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss am/pm"   'change to any date-based number format you prefer the cells to display
End With

End Sub

Comment: `.NumberFormat` formats **Numbers**. You need to change your string into a real Excel date/time in order to format it.  Plenty of examples on this forum as to how to do it. Try one or more; then, if you still have problems, edit your question to provide information as to what you have tried and where it did not work. Read about how Excel stores and parses dates.

Comment: `09:27:60` is that right? Shouldn't it be `09:28:00`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it splitting each part and forcing them into dates. Then sum up and then change format:

[image]

```
Sub changeformat()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
    Cells(i, 1).Value = CDate(Replace(Split(Cells(i, 1), " ")(0), ".", "/")) + CDate(Split(Cells(i, 1), " ")(1))
    Cells(i, 1).NumberFormat = ("dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss am/pm")
Next i

End Sub
```

After executing code I get:

[image]

Notice the value `9.12.20 09:27:60` can't be converted because `09:27:60` **is not** a valid time. Seconds always go from 00 to 59, not from 1 to 60. So actually `09:27:60` should be `09:28:00`

I'm afraid you'll need to code an exception for this cases.

Answer (score 1):

As shown by the fact that, when in General format, the cell is still displaying a date/time string, the date/time stamps are Text strings and not "real" Excel dates (which are stored as days and fractions of a day).

First we have to convert the string to a "real" date.  Then one can use the `.NumberFormat` property to display it in a cell however we want.

Fortunately, the format seems fixed so we can split on the dot/space and colon to get the different date/time parts.

The code below assumes

- all the dates are text strings
- the number format codes for dates are `mdy` and for time `hms`

As written, the results will be written in the adjacent column. To change it in place, see the comments in the code.

```
Option Explicit
Sub dateFixer()
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim rSrc As Range, rRes As Range
    Dim V, W, X, I As Long
    
With ActiveSheet
    Set rSrc = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    
    'set rRes = rSrc to overwrite original
    Set rRes = rSrc.Offset(rowoffset:=0, columnoffset:=1)
End With

'read into vba array for speedy processing
vSrc = rSrc

'Dim output array
ReDim vRes(1 To UBound(vSrc, 1), 1 To UBound(vSrc, 2))

'process the string dates
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    V = Split(vSrc(I, 1), ".") '0=day, 1 = month
    W = Split(V(2), " ")  ' 0=year
    X = Split(W(1), ":")   ' 0,1,2 = hr:min:sec
    
    vRes(I, 1) = DateSerial(W(0), V(1), V(0)) + TimeSerial(X(0), X(1), X(2))
Next I

'Write the results back to the worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss"
End With

End Sub
```

[image]